# Optional include in ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

Can I optionally include a partial if only it exists?

For example,

```
<%- include('some-template'); %>
```

should be complied to:

**if `some-template.ejs` exists:**

```
// content of some-template.ejs
```

**if `some-template.ejs` does not exist:**

```
// nothing
```

Currently, it throws an error if the partial not exists, like:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'some-template'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enclose it with a **if** that checks the existence of the file:

```
<% if (fs.existsSync('views/some-template.ejs')) { %>
    <%- include('some-template'); %>
<% } %>
```

Make sure your 'views' folder match the path inside the condition.

Also, you must send the fs object to the engine, so that it can be used in the scriptlet of the parent template:

```
res.render("main-template", {
    fs: fs
});
```